# grunt-html-build - process variable inside section?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-html-build

i am trying to build a page with templates, where i am setting some parameters.
Inside the main template this works perfect:

```
<!-- build:process -->
    <%= variable %>
<!-- /build -->
```

is correctly replaced by:

```
Value
```

To write the header only once, i have it in a separate file and include it as section, which works fine.

```
<!--  build:section header -->
<!-- /build -->
```

But the variables inside the header section are not processed and the partial template is included as it is:

```
<!-- build:process -->
    <%= variable %>
<!-- /build -->
```

What am i doing wrong here?
Do i need to configure something so the sections are also processed?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the `grunt-html-build` module.

The only quick decent solution I can propose is to process header separately to temporary file:

```
var grunt = require('grunt')
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html-build')

grunt.initConfig({
    htmlbuild: {
        header: {
            src: 'head.html',
            dest: 'temp/head.html', // << write processed header to temp file
            options: {
                data: {
                    variable: "Value"
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            src: 'body.html',
            dest: 'build/',
            options: {
                sections: {
                    header: 'temp/head.html' // << read processed header
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I had something in mind like that,  but did not get to the rather easy solution you proposed. Thx

Comment: @IceScorpion you can also submit this to the [repo](https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build). And if this answer solves your problem you can mark it as a solution

Answer (score -1):

You can process sections by using the `recursive` option: [view doc](https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build/wiki/Creating-HTML-Sections#recursive-option).

Comment: Please post what the link is doing in detail in the answer here itself, the link might change and then become inaffective